# How to Install mysql with my install.jar?

Tags: java, jar, izpack

I am using izpack to create installer for my java application. I have to install mysql before jar installed and also i want to start my jar automatically after installation completed. How can i do any help please..

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to require each user to have a MySQL Server installed on his workstation in order to work with your application, and putting the correct Connector in place?

- Replace it with remote server
- Use a textfile database
- Use a lighter DBMS (atleast something easier than a full MySQL installation)

If you MUST use a local MySQL, there exist [automated installers](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) that can do that for you.

Comment: After installed my jar using izpack installer, how can i initiate my application automatically..